# How do i understand python global variable's id?

Tags: python

```
foo = 1
print(foo,id(foo))

def f(num):
    global foo
    foo = num
    print(foo,id(foo))

f(1)
f(2)
```

output:

> 1 139831888361184
>   1 139831888361184
>   2 139831888361216

why foo's id in fun method changed in different argument even though I declared foo is a global variable?

Comment: That's due to Integer Interning. The `1` inside the function and outside are actually the same object, while the `2` is a different object.

Comment: @rdas thanks, i understand.